# Searching browser contents after automated form submission

Tags: c#, c, watin

Im using WatiN to automate form submissions on my website. The problem Im having is I cant find any documentation on how to search the page after submission and verify if a string is present or not. I need it to look for a string in the resulting page, and if it is present continue inserting the next variable in a list, if it is NOT present I need it to log what string was inserted that caused the text not to show up, preferably in a text file. Heres my code so far.

```
browser.GoTo("https://site.com");
        // locate the form by name and fill it
        browser.TextField(Find.ByName("form")).TypeText("example");
        // click the submit button
        browser.Button(Find.ByName("submit")).Click();
```

Unfortunately that's all I've gotten. Help is appreciated, I just need to be pushed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Use `browser.ContainsText("text to find")` to verify if a string is present or not.

```
string[] textToAddList = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Syd\Desktop\list.txt");

browser.GoTo("https://site.com");

foreach (string textToAdd in textToAddList)
{
    browser.TextField(Find.ByName("form")).TypeText(textToAdd);
    browser.Button(Find.ByName("submit")).Click();
    browser.WaitUntilComplete();
    if (!browser.ContainsText("text to find"))
    {
        //Log here
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Im sorry Im still confused, Im having trouble plugging my text file into "string textToAdd in textToAddList"

Comment: getting closer. Im attempting to declare list via "string[] textToAdd = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Syd\Desktop\list.txt");" and it seems to be workign fine but it still is giving me errors with "string textToAdd in textToAddList" saying textToAddList does not exist.

Comment: You have to declare `textToAddList` not `textToAdd` like this `string[] textToAddList = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Syd\Desktop\list.txt");`